# Controlling notification center IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make an alarm clock app that rings when a certain notification is received such as a email. I know the built-in notification center does this already, but is it possible to create my own within my app. I just need to be headed in the right direction. If it isn't possible is it possible to direct them to the native notification center through my app?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're asking, in effect: can anyone's app just read all of the user's email? No, it can't. Can it just run in the background and read all of their notifications? No, it can't.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule a local notification take a look of this.

Local notification allow you to schedule a notification. The other option is to use push notifications and send the notification through a web service. In your case I think a local notification will work.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html